# How can I set permissions so that users can only see their own uploaded documents? Sharepoint Online (Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

We are using Sharepoint Online (Office 365).

We have multiple users that submit documents on a recurring basis in a specific folder. Is there a way to set permissions so that an uploader can only see and edit their own uploaded documents? Site owners should be able to see all documents.

Answer (score 4):

yes...there are two ways.. one is via coding where if login users are same as CreatedBy field than the documents will be visible or if user is with Owner access he will be able to see the documents.

second is via out of box...create two views... One view display all documents and set its Audience Target to be only Owners... And create a second view where you have to create Filter on field Created By as [Me]. This will display only the items created by login users. When Owners login they will click on the first view where they will find all data.

Comment: In regards to the views solution - this might be fine if the documents aren't particularly sensitive, as the end user could easilly create their own view and remove any filters.  I would recommend going a step further and tweaking user's permissions on that library so that they can't create personal views via the "Manage Personal Views" permission.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use SharePoint's draft item security here.

Within the document library settings, select versioning settings then select the following:

1. Require content approval for submitted items - yes
2. Create major and minor (draft) versions
3. Under draft item security select 'only users can approve items (and the author of the item).

[image: Versioning settings]

Ensure that the site owners are part of the approvers group and they should then be able to see all items in the library (draft or published), whereas normal users who are not part of the approvers group can only see their own items.

Log in as both a normal user and a site owner to check that what you can see is correct.

Comment: This only affects draft versions of the user's documents.  As soon as the document is published, everyone will be able to see it.